# Search the different number in array, when all the other numbers are same , can this be done in O(logn) using divide and conquer

Tags: java, algorithm, search

Lets say we have a very large array and we need to find the only different number in the array, all the other numbers are the same in the array, can we find it in O(log n) using divide and conquer, just like mergeSort, please provide an implementation.

Comment: Is the array sorted?

Comment: Is the array sorted? If it is, the different number is either the first element or the last element and you can find it in `O(1)` time.

Comment: In order to find the different number you'll have, in the worst case, to iterate the whole array, which means that you can't do it in less than O(n)

Comment: `can we find it in O(log n) using divide and conquer, just like mergeSort` - merge sort takes `O(nlog(n))` not `O(log n)`.

Comment: Yeah,  @Eran I know, I meant if we can divide the array as we do in merge-sort and compare the divided array when the array size is 2, can we do it in less than O(n)? As dividing the array will be O(log n)  and comparing 2 elements when array is reduced to size 2 will be O(1)

Comment: @Hiresh At the worst case you'll have to compare n/2 pairs of elements, so you can't avoid the O(n).

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done in better time complexity than O(n) unless that array is special. With the constraints you have given, even if you apply an algorithm like divide and conquer you have to visit every array element at least once.

> As dividing the array will be O(log n) and comparing 2 elements when array is reduced to size 2 will be O(1)

This is wrongly put. Dividing the array is not O(log n). The reason why something like a binary search works in O(log n) is because the array is sorted and that way you can discard the other half of the array at every step even without looking at what elements they have, thereby halving the size of original problem.

Intuitively, you can think this as follows : Even if you keep on dividing the array into halves, the leaf nodes of the tree formed are n/2 (Considering you compare 2 elements at leaf). You will have to make n/2 comparisons, which leads to asymptotic complexity of O(n).